# Is there a way to split up a message based off special characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to make a discord bot with a command title "reactionrole". In this command I would like to let the user create an embed using a single message. For example, (-reactionrole "title blah blah" / "description blah blah" / "role1" "role2" / "emoji1" "emoji2") would be sent as a Discord message. Here's what I've tried so far

```
name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message:any, args:any, Discord:any, client:any) {
        const slicePoint = ('/');
        var segments = message.content.includes(slicePoint.length).split(slicePoint);
         var msg = message.content;
         var segments = msg.split('/');
         var firstRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role:any) => role.name === segments[2]);
         var firstEmoji = segments[3];
         var secondRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((role:any) => role.name === segments[2]);
         var secondEmoji = segments[3];

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setTitle(segments[0])
         .setDescription(segments[1])
```

and then there'd also be some reactions that would be added based off Segments 2 and 3 but I already know how to make that. If anyone could help that'd be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you mean like a separator?

```js
const separated = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" / ")
console.log(separated[1])
//This should serve what you're trying to achieve
// If I send a message like !separate hello :) / there, if u log them, you'd get 'hello :)' and 'there' separately
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would work but for some reason message.content isn't working in this specific command. No matter what I try if I put message.content it just doesn't seem to like it

Comment: Yes I have message in my handler. Whenever I run the code it doesn't give me an error message either which is what really confuses me.

Comment: did u check with other commands or is it just this

Comment: I checked with other commands it seems to only be this one that doesn't work. It also just makes the other commands stop working once I run this one once. For instance I can do -clear 2 and it works but if I run -reactionrole then run -clear 2 it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the problem is the use of `message` as an identifier conflicting with the built-in `Window.message` event. Use another identifier.

Comment: what other identifier should I use then? I used message on a lot of other commands and they all worked so I'm curious as to why this one is different

Comment: Anything that's not a js keyword. It may not be the problem but that's the first thing I'd do given that `message` has meaning in js.

Comment: Do you mean the `var msg` part?

Comment: How would it conflict with the [message event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event)? `message` is not a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: @Zsolt-Meszaros I've since tested it and my suspicion was wrong. I raised it as a possibility because the behaviour described in earlier discussion "but for some reason message.content isn't working in this specific command" and " if I put message.content it just doesn't seem to like it" and "I checked with other commands it seems to only be this one that doesn't work." all being typical when there is an unepected conflict dependent on what the js interpretter thought the command was  referencing. I'll be deleting my answer shortly

Comment: @Zsolt-Meszaros The last example I came across was a user-declared function that they'd named `getSelection`. This is not a reserved key word but is a property of the Window object. The function could never be invoked by the click event intended to run it but any other choice of name worked fine. Illustrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/DaveCP/u7ma584b/